# BlueSKy Summary Numerical Statistical Analysus

Tags: summary, quantile

If I only want to get different quartiles instead of defaults, I do not get the result. For example, if I am interested to obtain 0.65 quantile I don't have the result using Summary + Numerical Statistical Analysis

Comment: Please tell us what your exact question is what you have tried to achive it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The question is that when I want to use in BlueSky the option "Summary" + "Numerical Statistical Analysis" the default is to get quantiles 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1. If you add, for example, 0.65 quantile the programme does not calculate  this quantile. There is no result for 0.65 quantile.